How can I optimize the performance of this numpy function
Is there any way optimizing the performance speed of this function?
def func(X):
    n, p = X.shape
    R = np.eye(p)
    delta = 0.0
    for i in range(100):
        delta_old = delta
        Y = X @ R

        alpha = 1. / n
        Y2 = Y**2
        Y3 = Y2 * Y
        W = np.sum(Y2, axis=0)

        transformed = X.T @ (Y3 - (alpha * Y * W))
        U, svals, VT = np.linalg.svd(transformed, full_matrices=False)
        R = U @ VT  # is used as a stopping criterion
        delta = np.sum(svals)
    
    return R

Naively, I thought using numba would help because of the loop (the actual number of loops is higher),
from numba import jit

@jit(nopython=True, parallel=True)
def func_numba(X):
    n, p = X.shape
    R = np.eye(p)
    delta = 0.0
    for i in range(100):
        delta_old = delta
        Y = X @ R

        alpha = 1. / n
        Y2 = Y**2
        Y3 = Y2 * Y
        W = np.sum(Y2, axis=0)

        transformed = X.T @ (Y3 - (alpha * Y * W))
        U, svals, VT = np.linalg.svd(transformed, full_matrices=False)
        R = U @ VT
        delta = np.sum(svals)  # is used as a stopping criterion
    
    return R


but to my surprise the numbaized function is actually slower. Why is numba not more effective in this case? Is there another option for me (preferably using numpy)?
Note: You can assume X to be a "tall-and-skinny" matrix.
MWE
import numpy as np

size = (10_000, 15)
X = np.random.normal(size=size)
%timeit func(X)  # 1.28 s
%timeit func_numba(X)  # 2.05 s


You're timing the compilation time, you need to call the numba function once before timing it. For me the numba function is faster, 133ms vs 142ms for the given shape. Also, delta_old is not accessed.

I did compile the function before and it still turned out slower. 133 vs 142 ms seems also like a minor difference likely to be within the sample variance no? Yes you're correct with  Delta_old , it's used for the stopping criterion but I could have removed it for testing.

Numba has its own (naive) implementation of Numpy. Numpy functions can be more optimized, but slower for small arrays (because there is no JIT to inline function, propagate constants, etc.). Here, I expect the SVD and matrix multiplication to take most of the time. These things are done in separate libraries: BLAS and LAPACK. As for basic operations, Numba can be faster mainly by using plain loops so to avoid memory-bound operations, expensive allocations, page faults, etc.

For these types of questions, you might use Code Review.

I get very-unstable timings with Numba on an AMD Zen2 CPU with Numpy 2.0.2 and Numba 0.60.0 as well as CPython 3.12.3. Sometimes Numba is significantly faster sometimes the opposite. See https://pastecode.io/s/pse5g4ah . It might be similar for you. Are your timings stable?

@JérômeRichard thanks, I did a profiling using cProfile and indeed the computation of transformed takes up most of the time followed by np.linalg.svd. I cannot confirm the instability you observe. My results are pretty stable (albeit an order of magnitude slower :( ). Curiously, with numpy 1 I got about 1.4-1.5 s. With numpy 2 I get between 1.8-2.0 s. I expected the contrary...

@mrconcerned thanks, noted for next time ! Wasn't aware of this platform

After some analysis, the matrix multiplications generating transformed and Y are the one taking most of the time. Numpy call an optimized BLAS function which is close to optimal on my machine for that. I succeed to improve a bit the performance with Numba loops but the speed up is not huge. You should not expect any strong performance improvement as long as you do these operations. Maybe there is some math trick to avoid them, but I do not think so...

Thank you, so then I follow the suggestions by Michael Hodel which got me a speed gain of about 20% on average. Better than nothing :)

I tried to rewrite some stuff to speed things up. The only things I changed (apart from some formatting maybe) were removing the computation of the unused delta, pulling the transposition of X out of the loop as well as factorizing out the multiplication with Y for the computation of transformed which results in one fewer multiplications.
def func2(X):
    n, p = X.shape
    R = np.eye(p)
    alpha = 1. / n
    XT = X.T
    for i in range(100):
        Y = X @ R
        Y2 = Y**2
        W = np.sum(Y2, axis=0)
        transformed = XT @ (Y * (Y2 - (alpha * W)))
        U, svals, VT = np.linalg.svd(transformed, full_matrices=False)
        R = U @ VT
    return R

When I compare this func2 it to the function func as follows
X = np.random.normal(size=(10_000, 15))
assert np.allclose(func(X), func2(X))
%timeit func(X)
%timeit func2(X)

I get a speedup of more than 1.5x (it's not always as nice as that, however)
197 ms ± 44.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
127 ms ± 21.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)


Converting to float32 gives another boost in speed, but I am not sure if it's safe in this scenario.   (To make it work: in func2:  R = np.eye(p, dtype=X.dtype),   call: func2(X.astype(np.float32))). Assertion fails, but errors are very small (in case of those random numbers)

Thanks that makes sense! Not the degree of speed up I was hoping for but better than nothing :) I'll wait a bit more to see if there's an even faster solution, otherwise I'll accept yours as an answer.

@dankal444 thanks for the idea. In my case R can also be complex. Though I could use float32 and complex64 instead of the higher precision versions as you point out.
